# Which module to select upon importing MAT_DIALOG_DATA?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular project, when I need to import `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` there are many options available.

I tried importing `@angular/material`and `@angular/material/dialog`, and both options work for me.

What I don't understand, why does angular have so many options for this `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`?

From my point of view it would be better to have only one place (module), where `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` is defined.

What I am missing here?

[image: MAT_DIALOG_DATA import options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because if you want to import only one module than there is no point importing all the module. There are various benefits of it one and most important is it reduce final bundle size which will be helpful in optimization

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog; // lower bundle size

import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material; // large bundle size
```

Comment: Thank you, it somehow clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 1):

As per official documents you should import 
`API reference for Angular Material dialog
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog`;

You can check  [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand, why do we have so many options for MAT_DIALOG_DATA.

Comment: It's like importing selected `module` as per our requirement rather than whole of it.